# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) - Read File from Command Line

Tags: fstream

Can someone find where my error is within this code? There's this course enrollment file that i must read from command line that has the class name and priority of different student IDs (ClassName StudentID Priority, for each line), and output three files (for each class) containing in order who gets in first. I'm not allowed to see the priority queue class, but the int is the priority of that student. Also, do I need three ofstreams for the three output files?

```
// Course Enrollment
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "p2priorityqueue.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

// Declare filename string, check if there are actually arguments, pass argv[1] (the file used
// during compilation) to filename variable;
string filename; 
if(argc > 0){ 
filename = argv[1];
} 

// Declare the three variables we will use for passing data to our priority queues. 
string classN;
string userID;
int userYear;

// Declare three Priority Queues for each CS class, each with a string for the student ID and int for
// priority.
PriorityQueue<string, int> pq352;
PriorityQueue<string, int> pq365;
PriorityQueue<string, int> pq332;

// Initialize the three Priority Queues as instructed
initialize(pq352);
initialize(pq365);
initialize(pq332);
// Create input file stream called "input", and three output streams for each class
ifstream input;
ofstream output1;
ofstream output2;
ofstream output3;

// Open the file passed at compilation 
input.open(filename.c_str());


// While loop that runs until file input stream is empty. The first word is 
passed to classN,
// the second is passed to userID, and the third to userYear. We then check 
what PQ that line should belong
// to by comparing classN to CS352, CS365, CS332.
while(!input.eof()){
    input >> classN >> userID >> userYear; 
    if(classN == "CS352"){
        push(pq352, userID, userYear);
    } 
    if(classN == "CS365"){
        push(pq365, userID, userYear);
    } 
    if(classN == "CS332"){
        push(pq332, userID, userYear);
    }
}
// close the file input stream. 
input.close();



output1.open("CS352");
while(!isEmpty(pq352)){
    output1 << pop(pq352);
    output1 << endl;
}
output1.close();

output2.open("CS365");
while(!isEmpty(pq365)){
    output2 << pop(pq365);
    output2 << endl;
}
output2.close();


output3.open("CS332");
while(!isEmpty(pq332)){
    output3 << pop(pq332);
    output3 << endl;
}
output3.close();

destroy(pq352);
destroy(pq365);
destroy(pq332);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising all of your variables to eliminate any uninitialized exceptions first.

It looks like you're trying to bit shift uninitialised variables.

Namely:

```
string classN = "";
string userID = "";
int userYear = -1;
```

These here can stay like this:

```
ifstream input;
ofstream output1;
ofstream output2;
ofstream output3;
```

You also need to guard against an uninitialized filename:

```
string filename; 
if(argc > 0){ 
    filename = argv[1];
} else {
    filename = "somefilename.txt"
}
```

Otherwise this like `input.open(filename.c_str());` will fail because filename is not initialised.

Comment: I intialized classN to "", userID to "", and userYear to 0, I get the same error.

Comment: Edit: There were other uninitialized variables I missed

Comment: I do not have access to p2priorityqueue.h. I have been provided the methods/functions I can use, but nothing else.

Comment: Did you initialize the ifstreams and ofstreams?

Comment: I edited it, I use this online submitter for my code and I can only do 4 attempts every 30 mins. I'll let you know if it works as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: I get a this error                                                                      
CourseE.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
CourseE.cpp:36:35: error: conversion from 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' to non-scalar type 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' requested
     ifstream input = new ifstream();
                                   ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: Sorry you don't need to initialise the ifstream and ofstream that way, I made a mistake. Please see my new changes in the edit.

Comment: I changed and submitted it, I am resulted with segmentation fault again.